# Is there any way to replace a specific string in a collection all over the MongoDB from Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Relation Model:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5fbcf721df079f4d03b5fc7c"),
"user1" : "A",
"user2" : "B",
"user3" : "C"
},
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5fbcf721df079f4d03b5fc7d"),
"user1" : "B",
"user2" : "C",
"user3" : "A"
},
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5fbcf721df079f4d03b5fc7e"),
"user1" : "B",
"user2" : "A",
"user3" : "C"
}
```

I want to replace all occurrences of A to D.

1. Is there any way to replace A -> D completely using MongoDB.
2. I was able to fetch all the data then use javascript replace to change the values and overwrite them is there any optimized solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You may try doing an update using `$switch`:

```
db.your_collection.update(
    { },
    [
        { $set: { user1: { $switch: {
            branches: [
                { case: { $eq: [ "$user1", "A" ] }, then: "D" },
            ],
            default: "$user1"
        } } } },
        { $set: { user2: { $switch: {
            branches: [
                { case: { $eq: [ "$user2", "A" ] }, then: "D" },
            ],
            default: "$user2"
        } } } },
        { $set: { user3: { $switch: {
            branches: [
                { case: { $eq: [ "$user3", "A" ] }, then: "D" },
            ],
            default: "$user3"
        } } } },
   ],
   { multi: true }
);
```

The logic above is to do a blanket update of every document in your collection.  We do a conditional update of the `userx` value for each of the 3 user columns, making an update from `A` to `D` only in the case that the value matches `A`.  Otherwise, we retain the original field value for each column.

Comment: Thanks, But what if I have more user fields like user1,user2,user3,user4... user15, or any other fields where I want to replace "A". In other words, I want to replace all the fields which have a value "A". Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: @VikasSuresh Most databases (including Mongo AFAIK) don't have shortened syntax for "update all columns."  You'll probably have to add `$set` clauses for each column which you want to target.  Or, consider changing your table design such that each user doesn't necessitate creating another field.

Comment: @VikasSuresh So my feeling here is that maybe a better design would be to have a separate Mongo BSON _document_ for every user, rather than a separate field.  But, the design choice is yours to make.

Comment: Got It, I will change the schema.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.cueck.updateMany({ },  // instead of  { } use a filter 
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "user1": { "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$user1", "A" ] }, "D",  "$user1" ] } 
      // add "," and more users here 
      } }
])
```

- You probably want to add a filter like so: `{field:{$eq:"A"}}`
- `$set` is an alias to `$addFields` you can use either.
- if you use updateMany, no need of `multi:true`.